# Python-Extracting data from Table (print rows)

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I would like to get the value of 'stock' from every row in this table. So i do the following:

```
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
portfolios = db.execute("SELECT stock, names, SUM(shares) AS nofshares, price FROM transactions WHERE id=:id GROUP BY stock", id=session["user_id"] )
for row in portfolios:
    print(row["stock"])
```

but when i run the program i get the entire row and only one of them:

```
{'stock': 'NKE', 'names': 'NIKE, Inc.', 'nofshares': 41, 'price': 83.23}
```

I dont know what im doing wrong. I would like to print the stock value from every row on that dictionary

THIS IS THE FUNCTION IM WORKING IN MY WEB:

`````````
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    portfolio = db.execute("SELECT stock, names, SUM(shares) AS nofshares, price FROM transactions WHERE id=:id GROUP BY stock", id=session["user_id"])
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("sell.html", portfolio=portfolio);
    if request.method == "POST":
        nofsharess = request.form.get("shares")
        symboltosell = request.form.get("symbol")
        for row in portfolio:
            if row["stock"] == symboltosell:
                if nofsharess > row["nofshares"]:
                    return apology("You dont have that many stocks to sell", 403);
        return redirect("/")
````````

THIS IS MY HTML AND WORKS FINE
````
{% block main %}
    <form action="/sell" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol">
                <option value="" selected data-default>Symbol</option>
                {% for row in portfolio %}
              <option value=symbol >{{ row.stock }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number" min="1">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
`````
`````````

Comment: Are you sure there are any other rows in your database?

Comment: can you add also print(row) in your question pls?

Comment: I checked my transactions table and its full of rows

Comment: and if you replace row["stock"] by row[0] ??

Comment: it returns "Keyerror: 0"

Comment: I will recommend you first test the code of your connection a execute in another file ...but alone ..

Comment: i cant really understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Try with some like this :

```
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT stock, names, SUM(shares) AS nofshares, price FROM transactions GROUP BY stock,names,price;")
for stock, names, nofshares, price in  cursor.fetchall():
    print(price)
```

Comment: It returns the exact same result :(

Comment: @nicoehrenbock can you add your full code?? and a few example about your data

Comment: With this code, i go to my page and set way more stocks than i have so i can test if my condition works, but it doesnt. Because somehow my dictionary only returns {'stock': 'NKE', 'names': 'NIKE, Inc.', 'nofshares': 41, 'price': 83.23}. I know that my db.execute....... works because i have usedit successfully in other functions. Even if i run sqlite3 in command line argument it returns the right amount of rows